# Building Meteor Smart Packages that work outside of Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, package, meteorite

So, I would like to build a Meteor Smart Package that works inside and outside of Meteor's run-time environment. Basically, the library would have less (or alternative) features when running outside of Meteor. In other words, my code would have this in it:

```
if (typeof Meteor !== 'undefined') {
    // Meteor specific functionality
}
```

Because I am developing this library as a smart package for Meteor, and I am relying on Meteor's package building system.

I discovered that when packages are built, the resulting combined source can be found in a .build folder in the package directory. Specifically, the code is in `.build/browser/packages/<somthing>.js` along with a sourcemap file. I also learned that I can trigger a build by using `meteor run-command .` in the package directory (btw triggering a build directly in this manner creates build files with a different naming scheme, which seems like a bug). Other than this naming quirk, this all works fine, and allows me to build packages that run outside of Meteor.

However, debugging is another matter. The generated sourcemap doesn't seem to line things up correctly in, for example, Chrome's developer tools, making it impossible to debug. Also, not including the sourcemap in the host environment doesn't help... But the Meteor-generated js file doesn't have a sourcemap comment, just commented line numbers at the end of each line, so I'm not really sure why it doesn't debug nicely. Any ideas on why this happens? I'd love to be able to use Meteor's build system in a way that allows me generate combined source that is debuggable too (outside of Meteor).

Comment: I know this doesn't exactly answer your question, but the general way to do this would be to make a generic project, and then make a separate Meteor package which is basically just a package.js file and a git submodule pointing to the actual project's repo.

Comment: Yeah, I just like the Meteor style of writing packages. All the components are already there to make this work, it's just the debugging thing I'm trying to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm still not entirely sure why it would have been a problem, but running the generated code through `uglifyjs --beautify` removes all the comments and allows the built package to be debugged without a problem. So, Yay. I can now use Meteor as a package building tool. :)